Diagonal action on infinite tensor product of the hyperfinite II_1 factor
Suppose $\mathcal{R}_0$ is the hyperfinite II$_1$ factor and suppose $\mathbb{Z}\curvearrowright^{\alpha} \mathcal{R}_0$ is an (outer) action. Let $\Gamma$ be an infinite group and form the infinite tensor product $\mathcal{R}_1=\mathcal{R}_0^{\otimes \Gamma}$. How is the $\textit{diagonal action}$ $\mathbb{Z}\curvearrowright^{\beta} \mathcal{R}_1$ defined? Is it defined as $$ \beta_n(\otimes \pi_{\gamma}(x_\gamma))= \otimes \pi_{\gamma} (\alpha_n(x_\gamma))$$ on elementary tensors?
If this is the right definition of the diagonal action, how can I show that $\langle \beta_n(\otimes \pi_{\gamma}(x_\gamma)),\beta_n(\otimes \pi_{\gamma}(y_\gamma))\rangle= \langle \otimes \pi_{\gamma}(x_\gamma),\otimes \pi_{\gamma}(x_\gamma)\rangle$ (because I want to rigoursly define $\beta_n$ on $\mathcal{R}_1$)? If it's true that $\tau_0(\alpha_n(x))=\tau_0(x)$ I can prove it but I don't see why this must be true ($\tau_0$ is the unique tracial state on $\mathcal{R}_0$).

$\tau_0$ is the unique tracial state on $\mathcal{R}_0$. As $\alpha_n$ is an automorphism, we see that $\tau_0 \circ \alpha_n$ is a tracial state on $\mathcal{R}_0$, so $\tau_0 = \tau_0 \circ \alpha_n$.
More generally, any automorphism, inner or outer, must preserve the trace on a II$_1$ factor.

Oh, it's that easy. Thanks
